# Formatar em R$ valores resgatados com SUM

Tags: php

Desejo mostrar os valores em formato moeda

```
include "conect.php";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(preco) as SOMA, cod FROM valores GROUP BY cod ORDER BY SOMA DESC";
$exec = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
     echo $rows["cod"]."-".$rows["SOMA"]."<br><br><br>";

}
```

Visualização:

BT01-151000

BT02-48000

BT03-22000

BT04-11000

Desejado:

BT01- R$ 1.510,00

BT02- R$ 480,00

BT03- R$ 220,00

BT04- R$ 110,00

Comment: E o código php?

Comment: <?php

include "conect.php";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(preco) as SOMA, cod FROM valores GROUP BY cod ORDER BY SOMA DESC";
$exec = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
  echo $rows["cod"]."-".$rows["SOMA"]."<br><br><br>";

}

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando a função do php `number_format`:

> Ref: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php

```
function formatar_valor($valor){
      return number_format($valor, 2, '.', '');
}


include "conect.php";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(preco) as SOMA, cod FROM valores GROUP BY cod ORDER BY SOMA DESC";
$exec = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
     echo $rows["cod"]."- R$ ".formatar_valor($rows["SOMA"])."<br><br><br>";
}
```